# What does the phrase "other criteria" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

By Definition:

> Criteria is a principle or standard by which something may be judged or decided.

Example on a resume:

> . . . Organizing deadlines, schedules, and other criteria.

Therefore, "other criteria" means "other standards." Is this the example above an acceptable usage?

EDIT

•   Organizing electronics team schedule, meetings, deadlines and other criteria

•   Designing electronics system layout in AutoCAD for reference and wiring harness construction

There is only bullet points listing my experience, not a paragraph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought a little bit about your example:

> . . . Organizing deadlines, schedules, and other criteria.

Deadlines, *and* schedules? This gets me skeptical. Maybe you wanted something like **et cetera**:

> et cetera (abbreviation: etc. or &c.) is a Latin expression that means "and other things", or "and so forth". It is taken directly from the Latin expression, which literally means "and the rest (of such things)" and is a calque of the Greek "καὶ τὰ ἕτερα" (kai ta hetera: "and the other things"; the more usual Greek form is "καὶ τὰ λοιπά" kai ta loipa: "and the remainder"). Et means "and"; cētera means "the rest". - [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Et_cetera)

---

### Extra fluff:

*etc.* is very common; however, if you're looking for other similar phrases/words used here, take a look at these:

[**and so on**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=and+so+on%2Cand+so+forth%2Cetc%2C+et+cetera&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cand%20so%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cand%20so%20forth%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cetc%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cet%20cetera%3B%2Cc0) is the most common replacement I can think of at the moment.

[image]

There's also [**"et al.", "among others" and "and suchlike"**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=and+suchlike%2C+among+others%2C+et+al&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cand%20suchlike%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Camong%20others%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cet%20al%3B%2Cc0). I'm not really sure though, if *et al.* fits your context very well, despite its overwhelming usage boost.

[image]

---

That being said, the phrase *other criteria* is commonplace in itself:

The Commonness ™ trial:

- [COCA](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/?c=coca&q=40751396): First two results are: "and other criteria." and "and other criteria,".
- Ngrams:
  [image]

[image]

- There are approximately [1.9M results](https://www.google.nl/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1PRFE_enIR614IR614&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22other+criteria%22+filetype:pdf), searching for PDF files that contain the exact phrase "other criteria".
- Approximately [4.5k results](https://www.google.nl/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1PRFE_enIR614IR614&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22other+criteria%22&tbm=bks) in Google books for "other criteria".

Comment: The full phrase is -Organizing electronics team schedule, meetings, deadlines and other criteria

Comment: It's just a bullet point on a resume.

Comment: Then maybe provide the whole paragraph? Tell us more about it. As Stumbler pointed out in the other answer, its use *could* be fishy.

Comment: Note: *et al.* is for shared authorship and similar: it applies to nothing but lists of people.

Comment: Agreed @Nathan. I suspected this was the case as I haven't seen it in any other context.

Answer (score 3):

I can tell you that usage is not correct, but I'm having a hard time articulating why, so I hope you will bear with me a little bit.

I think the biggest issue is that one does not "organize criteria". The typical verbs associated with "criteria" are "to create", "to meet", "to give", "to define". For instance, one version of my resume says

> Ensured all criteria were met to receive federal grants.

Another is that "criteria" is not typically used in isolation. It is generally criteria **for** something. In my example above it is criteria for receiving federal grants.

Finally, criteria are usually verbs. I would not say

> The criteria for receiving federal grants include deadlines and schedules.

Instead I would say

> The criteria for receiving federal grants include **meeting** deadlines and **following** schedules.

To sum up, I would rewrite your example to say:

> Ensuring deadlines, schedules, and other criteria are met.

One final note: In common usage criteria is both the plural and the singular, but in technical and professional writing you should know that criteria is plural. To use the singular you should say a set of criteria, or a criterion. So a list of requirements for an object to be considered alive would be a set of criteria, and one of those criteria would be the criterion that it grows.

Comment: The OP accepted my answer, so it seems they *were* looking for *and so forth/etc.*. However, your recommended sentence really works IMO, so you have my +1.

Answer (score 2):

Your definition is correct. However, I would not consider the example to be acceptable usage.

You are saying "organising/organizing deadlines, schedules, and other criteria"

This means that you consider deadlines and schedules to be criteria in themselves. I don't think they are.

Furthermore, using the word "criteria" invites the question of what it is a criteria *of*.

> I helped develop the criteria upon which the acceptance of applicants was determined.

Having said that, there's nothing wrong with the term "other criteria" in of itself.

In your resumé I would question the use of the word "other", because I doubt that anything you are going to finish up that sentence with is likely to fall within the same category as the preceding items.

Comment: +1 I agree that it would hardly be acceptable. The OP vaguely accepted my answer, thus I *think* they were looking for *et cetera*.